# How do I make nicknames using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a server and an adventure map and I wanted to create a class system with command blocks that shows a nickname like "warrior", "archer", and stuff like that, but I don't know how. I know this is possible because Hypixel did it as well in his map, The Wither's Challenge.

Comment: I believe this is done using the [scoreboard teams commands](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Scoreboard#Teams), but I'll let someone who has actually used the scoreboard feature post a proper answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, the fact that modded servers like Hypxiel do something does not mean that it is possible to do that thing with just commands.

Answer (score 7):

First, you should add the teams that you want as normal:

[image]

For the next part you will need something to edit the NBT data of the world, such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/).

Navigate to your world, and inside that, open `data` > `scoreboard.dat` > `data` > `Teams`.

Now you should see some `7 entries`, these are your teams that you created. You can open them up and check the `Name`s inside to see which is which.

[image]

You should see that one of the tags each team has is a `Prefix` and a `Suffix`. From here you simply need to double click on the Prefix/Suffix you want to change, and enter the string that you it want to show up as. You can make it anything, and use [Formatting Codes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes) to add colour or effects.

[image]

(Note I did **2** s/p for Team_**1** and **1** s/p for Team_**2**)

Once you've changed what you want and saved, these should show up as the prefix and suffix of the teams in game.

[image]

Comment: There is no need to use a NBT explorer. You can change prefix/suffix with commands directly: `team modify <team> <prefix/suffix> <JSON text>`. See [here](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/team)

Answer (score 0):

Dragnoz has made a [really cool video explaining how to achieve just that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaN_VokszzI). He makes other helpful videos too, so you should really check him out, especially when you're creating a map.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, since it makes the answer useful only so long as the link still works. Could you summarise the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the command block placed and you have the *Minecraft Essentials Plugin*, and you'd like to give a certain nickname to every player who presses a button on the command block, simply input this into the command block command:

```
/nick @p (nickname you want them to have)
```

If you want to make them able to have a choice of nicknames, you can make several of these four blocks apart with a different nickname in each of them.

Also, *make sure command blocks are enabled*.

[Reference for other command block-related things here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block)

Answer (score 0):

`/nick` doesn't work without a bukkit server plugin, but you first do `/scoreboard teams add <name> (doesn't matter)` then `/scoreboard teams option <the chosen name> color <the chosen color>`

Comment: The OP asked for a text nickname, not just a color change