# How can I change my username temporarily on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to change my name in Vanilla Minecraft but I **don't** want it permanent. Going to www.minecraft.net just gives you a permanent new name. I just want it in the game for a short time.

Is there a command or something like that that can do this?

Comment: There are a few different ways to temporarily change your username; [faking it with command blocks](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/219197/54474), [changing it in the JSON profile data](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/148410/54474) or [editing the world's NBT data to modify the prefix/suffix](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/131271/54474). As the answer states, changing it on [minecraft.net](http://www.minecraft.net) also isn't permanent, just 30 days.

Answer (score 5):

Changing your name on minecraft.net is not permanent, but it is locked for 30 days.

Other than that, there may be custom servers that will work with a Vanilla client that allow name changes, but in completely vanilla Minecraft there is no other way to change your name.

Comment: Please add: Your old username is 'Taken' for 37 days so that you can change back if you don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the Youtuber, OMGChad. He shows a video of how to change your minecraft username or read below.

How do I create a username?
You create a username during the Minecraft purchase process, or if you have a prepaid card, during card redemption. ​You'll need to sign up for a Mojang account. After you're logged in, you can buy a Minecraft account or redeem a gift code or prepaid card.

Where can I find my username?
If you log into Minecraft with your email, your username can be found in your account overview. If you log into Minecraft with a username, and you've forgotten it, you can have it sent to you.

I've paid, but don't have a username. How do I create one?
If you somehow made a purchase, but didn't get a username, a green box will appear on your Mojang profile prompting you to choose a username.

Changing a username

Can I change my username?
Users who have a Mojang account (you sign in with your email) can change their username for free at account.mojang.com/me by clicking the (Change) link next to your profile name. If you sign in with your username, you'll need to migrate to a Mojang account. After clicking the change link, you'll be able to see if a username is available to you. If it shows that it is not available, you will not be able to change to that name.

How often can I change my username?
If you've changed your username already, you'll need to wait 30 days to be able to make a change. Newly-created usernames will also need to wait for a time before they are able to change their name.

What happens to my old username after I've changed?
If you change your username, your old name is held for 37 days. This gives you an extra week to change back if you've made a mistake or changed your mind.

How far back does this work?
Username changes can be fully supported in-game as of Minecraft version 1.7.10 (released June 2014). If you were to play on a very old version of Minecraft, the game would treat your new username as a separate player. This article assumes that you are using a somewhat recent version of the game or server software.

If I ban someone on my server, and they change their username, do they stay banned?
Yes, and the same is true for whitelisted or OP'd players. Account-level features on an unmodified server stay the same because the system is using your profile's unique ID instead of the username. This does not include the scoreboard feature, which uses usernames, and is not meant to store lots of long-term player data.

If I change my username, can someone see my previous usernames?
Yes. Username changes are set up so that you can get a username that you prefer, and are not designed to circumvent bans or anything of that sort.

How will this work with mods/VIP/Uber Omega Obsidian Rank on servers?
Ask the mod maker or server owner, they'll know. Mods should be able to support this system easily, and most already do, but we aren't responsible for private servers or mods.

Will Mojang Support help me change my username?
No. The system is set up so that users can change their own usernames. If you don't like your username, you can change it again in 30 days.

What about username moderation? Can I report someone?
Mojang has always had a pretty relaxed stance on usernames. Someone who chooses an inappropriate username is often banned by the servers that they join. Even though username changes are now a feature, people have been able to register questionably appropriate usernames since 2009, and the community has self-regulated. Implementing a comprehensive username filter is actually quite difficult, and doing so would diminish the openness that has made the game so popular. We would prefer not to have players constantly reporting each other via this help site; instead, please contact your server administrator. That said, we reserve the right to change particularly offensive names to something more cheerful, as needed.

-ShadowGamer2034